# Subpage In Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I tried applying some solutions I've found online but I can't seem to have any of them work for me. (I'm fairly new to Laravel) I'm trying to get Laravel to direct to blade views I set up. However, I want to be able to access them via sub-page urls. Could I get some help? The URLs I'm using to at the moment are

```
/course/{course_slug}
/lesson/{lesson_slug}
/module/{module_slug}
```

I have course.blade.php , lesson.blade.php, and module.blade.php set up. (not sure why it doesn't let me post my code)

But I want to be able to route to these views using this syntax:

```
/course/{course-slug}
/course/{course-slug}/{lesson-slug}
/course/{course-slug}{lesson-slug}/{module-slug}
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you so much.

Erwin

EDIT: Code used for blade files (changing out the module variable to lesson, course, etc)

```
@foreach($modules as $modules)
        <li>
            <a href="/modules/{{ $lesson->lesson_slug}}/{{ $modules->module_slug }}">

                <span>{{ $modules->module_title }}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

Here's my routes file code:

```
Route::get('course/{slug}', function($slug){
    $course= App\Course::where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    $lessons = App\Lesson::where("course_id", "=", $course->id)->get();
    return view('course', compact('course'))->with('lessons', $lessons);
});

Route::get('lesson/{slug}', function($slug){
    $lesson = App\Lesson::where('lesson_slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    $modules = App\Module::where("lesson_id", "=", $lesson->id)->get();
    return view('lesson', compact('lesson'))->with('modules', $modules);
});

Route::get('module/{slug}', function($slug){
    $module = App\Module::where('module_slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    return view('module', compact('module'));
});
```